# Resource about linear algebra over finite field, actually $F_2^n$ is enough for me

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation, coding-theory, online-resources

I am working with the finite field $F_2$ which contains the elements $(0,1)$. The $+$ law is then done modulo $2$.

$F_2^n$ can be seen as an $F_2$ vector space. The problem I am facing is that I learnt linear algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. And I don't know what is still true when dealing with finite fields. A typical issue I faced was with orthogonality. Here the example:

We can define orthogonality properties based on the dot product, for instance for $n=3$, we have: $(010).(111)=0+1+0=1$

This is typically done in coding theory. Now the thing that confuses me a lot is that this dot product will not verify the standard axiom of an inner product,
basically the positive condition. For instance, we can have the "weird" case in which $x.x = 0$ when $x \neq 0$. An example would be $(11).(11)=1+1=0$. Vectors that are self orthogonal exists !

Because of that, all my intuitions breaks down about what is true or not when dealing with finite fields.

**I am thus looking for a nice book, dealing with the basics of linear algebra that works with finite fields (not only over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)**. My main concern is that I don't have time to go in full details of such object. I really just need to get the basic intuition of what changes with respect to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. And in practice I will only need to work with $F_2^n$.

Comment: Note:  this is not an inner product, but a symmetric bilinear form given by the dot product.  The 'weird case' you are referring to is that of self-orthogonal vectors which are non-zero.

Comment: @user8675309 thanks I edited

Comment: since you are using a dot product for your sym bilinear form, the expedient way to understand things is to push through the ideas using linear algebra over $\mathbb F_2$. E.g. come up with a basis for your $V$ and have these coordinate vectors be the rows of some matrix $A$.  Then $V^{\perp}$ is the nullspace of $A$.  Rank-nullity (and row rank = col rank) then gives your dim addition formula.  Just make sure you know basic linear algebra over $\mathbb F_2$ -- many people haven't learned anything other than matrices over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ for some reason and it becomes problematic.

Comment: @user8675309 I indeed mainly now linear algebra over real or complex. But apart from those orthogonal aspect are there that much things changing when going to linear algebra with finite field ?

Comment: @user8675309 I edited again

Comment: Mostly things change only if they deal with magnitude, distances, etc. For example, the statement that "$x \cdot x \geq 0$" is meaningless over a finite field.  Most things that don't involve these concepts (and angles, volumes, etc) hold. "Inner products" are one thing that is thrown out; you don't have inner products over finite fields. But you have bilinear/sesquilinear forms. Studying these should take you a long way.

Comment: You most likely do need a fairly good understanding of finite fields, polynomials, groups (linear and permutation), and a theoretical understanding of linear algebra to do much interesting in coding theory (including studying properties of fields of order $2^{n}$, and not just order 2). So you are probably restricting yourself a bit much asking for books that avoid the abstract.

Comment: @user8675309 Hello. Sorry I am probably too annoying with my question. Well after seeing this book forget about my not too abstract condition and the restriction to $F_2$. A book of linear algebra which results holds for finite field would be enough. The reason I don't want something too heavy is that I really only need the few basics of that. I am studying quantum error correction and very few notions of linear algebra on finite fields are required. And I would like to avoid spending days/weeks to master the topic.

Comment: @MorganRodgers look at last comment.

Comment: since you have a recent question about Lagrange's theroem I take it you know rudiments of group theory.  My actual recommendation is to go through the first 4 chapters of Artin's Algebra 1st edition (which is a lot cheaper than 2nd ed).  This covers the bulk of linear algebra over $\mathbb R,\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb F_p$.  If you are only looking for a 'shortcut' so you don't need to go through 4 chapters, then I don't have anything to contribute.

Comment: @user8675309 I took a look and this book looks really nice. Thanks.