# Books for vector spaces over finite fields

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am interested in exploring vector spaces over finite fields. In many linear algebra books, the vector space over finite fields is not discussed in detail. I request you to suggest some textbooks which discuss vector spaces over finite fields in significant detail. (if it is suitable for self-study then it is a bonus!)

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246082/sources-for-vector-spaces-over-finite-fields)

Comment: Books on abstract algebra also have a chapter on finite fields themselves. Finite extensions of finite fields are also vector spaces over finite fields. Also Galois's main theorem for finite fields could be helpful. Or are you interested in coding theory? Then linear algebra over finite fields is often asked for, see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913163/resource-about-linear-algebra-over-finite-field-actually-f-2n-is-enough-for), asking this.

Comment: From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516659/first-course-in-linear-algebra-and-matrices-over-arbitrary-fields): "If you're looking for linear algebra over finite fields, I recommend Lidl and Niederreiter's *big red book* called *Finite Fields*. This is a book about the theory of finite fields in general, but this tends to involve lots of linear algebra anyway on account of how finite fields are studied.".

Comment: J.W.P. Hirschfeld. Projective Geometries over Finite Fields. Oxford University Press, 2nd edition, 1998.